# Tweak the iOS bonding request dialog

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

We are shoe-horning BLE into an existing device, and unfortunately this device has a very limited display and can only display 4 digits.

We would like to use Numeric Comparison mode for the best security, but it generates a PIN that is 6 characters long.  Is there any way to tweak the iOS "device wants to pair" dialog to show 4 digits?  Or even take over the dialog completely to show the user a more exact representation of how the PIN will be displayed on our particular device?  I'm pretty sure there's no way to tell BLE to generate a 4-digit PIN ...

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can't display every six digit decimal number as a four digit decimal hex number, so what do you want to show as 4 hex digits?

Comment: Good point, my bad, even 4 hex digits doesn't do the job.  I'll remove that part of my post.